# Java - Sorting Array by time

Tags: java, sorting, datetime

First: I use a Array for informations like this:

```
// Tuesday
array[2][1] = "tuesday";
array[2][2] = "20:00";

// Wednesday 
array[3][1] = "Wednesday";
array[3][2] = "15:00";

// Thursday 
array[4][1] = "Thursday";
array[4][2] = "20:00";

// Friday
array[5][1] = "Friday";
array[5][2] = "18:00";

// Saturday
array[6][1] = "Saturday";
array[6][2] = "15:00";

// Sunday
array[7][1] = "Sunday";
array[7][2] = "15:00";
```

How can I sort the Array by actually Time AND Weekday?
Example: Now it's  Wednesday - 11:13. The first Array-Item will be the array[3], then 4,5,6,7 and then again 2.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Your code suffers from the *Object Denial* smell, which will make everything, including your current issue, more difficult to do. Java wants you to write classes, don't resist.

Comment: Today is Wednesday - 11:35 german time.
3(today, 15:00), 4 (after wednesday is thursday),5,6,7,2 (because after Sunday is (in this array) tuesday (no monday)). I edit my Question: actually Time AND Week Day.

Comment: I would be tempted to say that Arrays are not the best data structure to use for this

Comment: Maybe, but what would be the best structure? A Link or a example would be helpfull.

Comment: Isn't it posible to change the way you save this information? Couldn't you use for instance Joda Time or XMLGregorianCalendar or your own object?

Comment: The best structure would be a Class. Example: `public class Schedule { private final String weekDay, timeOfDay; }`

Comment: Its possible iberbeu. The target is to learn that. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other Answers here are good, but use outmoded classes.

## java.time

With Java 8 and later we now have the java.time framework built-in (with back-ports for Java 6 & 7 and Android). A vast improvement over the old date-time classes.

The java.time classes include a pair of classes that fit your exact needs:

- [`DayOfWeek`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html)
  A handy [enum](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) to represent each of the seven days of the week, as defined by the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard running from Monday to Sunday.
- [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html)
  Represents a time-of-day without date and without time zone.

With these types pre-defined, you do not even need to define your own class as suggested by other comments and answers. At least if your definition of sorting the days runs Monday-Sunday. The `DayOfWeek` enum has predefined days of the weeks in that order. You *could* make your own class combining the `DayOfWeek` and `LocalTime` if it makes sense your greater project.

[Java enums](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) are *really* handy, flexible, and powerful (so [learn more](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html) if they are new to you). Enums have their own special implementation of [`Set`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) and [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), named appropriately, [`EnumSet`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumSet.html) and [`EnumMap`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html). We can use an `EnumMap` to track each day of the week, mapping it to the time-of-day (a `LocalTime` object).

```
EnumMap<DayOfWeek , LocalTime> dayToTimeMap = new EnumMap<> ( DayOfWeek.class );

dayToTimeMap.put ( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , LocalTime.parse ( "20:00" ) );
dayToTimeMap.put ( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , LocalTime.of ( 15 , 0 ) );
dayToTimeMap.put ( DayOfWeek.THURSDAY , LocalTime.parse ( "20:00" ) );
dayToTimeMap.put ( DayOfWeek.FRIDAY , LocalTime.parse ( "18:00" ) );
dayToTimeMap.put ( DayOfWeek.SATURDAY , LocalTime.parse ( "15:00" ) );
```

Get the current day-of-week and time-of-day.

```
DayOfWeek today = DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY;
LocalTime now = LocalTime.of ( 11 , 13 );
```

Make a pair of empty sets one to track the day-times that are the same or later than today-now, and one to track the earlier day-times. Being `EnumSet`, their natural order is the order declared in the `DayOfWeek` enum (Monday-Sunday, 1-7).

```
EnumSet<DayOfWeek> earlier = EnumSet.noneOf ( DayOfWeek.class );
EnumSet<DayOfWeek> later = EnumSet.noneOf ( DayOfWeek.class );
```

Loop the DayOfWeek-to-LocalTime map. See if the DayOfWeek is before, equal to, or later than today. If equal to today, the compare its `LocalTime` object to our `now` object. Assign this DayOfWeek object to either the `earlier` set or the `later` set.

```
for ( Map.Entry<DayOfWeek , LocalTime> entry : dayToTimeMap.entrySet () ) {
    DayOfWeek key = entry.getKey ();
    LocalTime value = entry.getValue ();
    int comparison = key.compareTo ( today );
    if ( comparison < 0 ) { // if earlier day…
        earlier.add ( key );
    } else if ( comparison == 0 ) { //If same day…
        if ( value.isBefore ( now ) ) {
            earlier.add ( key );
        } else {  // Else same time as now or later than now…
            later.add ( key );
        }
    } else if ( comparison > 0 ) {
        later.add ( key );
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException ( "Unexpectedly reached IF-ELSE for comparison: " + comparison );
    }
}
```

Dump to console. We want to loop the `later` set first, then the `earlier` set per the requirements laid out in the Question.

```
System.out.println ( "dayToStringMap: " + dayToTimeMap );
System.out.println ( "sorted by today: " + today + " " + now + " is: " );
for ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek : later ) {
    LocalTime localTime = dayToTimeMap.get ( dayOfWeek );
    System.out.println ( dayOfWeek + " " + localTime );
}
for ( DayOfWeek dayOfWeek : earlier ) {
    LocalTime localTime = dayToTimeMap.get ( dayOfWeek );
    System.out.println ( dayOfWeek + " " + localTime );
}
```

When run.

```
dayToStringMap: {TUESDAY=20:00, WEDNESDAY=15:00, THURSDAY=20:00, FRIDAY=18:00, SATURDAY=15:00}
sorted by today: WEDNESDAY 11:13 is: 
WEDNESDAY 15:00
THURSDAY 20:00
FRIDAY 18:00
SATURDAY 15:00
TUESDAY 20:00
```

Answer (score 6):

You should use `Arrays.sort(array,comparator)`, e.g. something like this:

```
Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    public int compareTo(String[] one, String[] two) {
         // implement compareTo here
    }
});
```

But it is very bad practice to use 2 dimensional array for different data instead of 1 dimensional array of custom type, i.e.:

```
public class DayTime {
    private String day;
    private String time;
    // constructors, setters, getters
}
```

Now create array like this:

```
DayTime[] days = new DayTime[] {
    new DayTime("tuesday", "20:00").
    new DayTime("Wednesday", "15:00"),
    // etc, etc
};


Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<DayTime>() {
    public int compareTo(DayTime one, DayTime two) {
         // implement compareTo here
    }
});
```

You can also make `DateTime` to implement `Comparable`. In this case just call `Arrays.sort(array)`

Answer (score 3):

```
class CalendarEntry implements Comparable<CalendarEntry> {
  String entry;
  Date start;

  // constructors, getters, setters

  int compareTo(CalendarEntry o) {
    if (o==null) return 1;
    return start.compareTo(o.start);
  }

}

List<CalendarEntry> entriesList = new ArrayList<CalendarEntry>();
// add contents
Collections.sort(entriesList);
// and you are done
```

Answer (score 1):

The sorting itself can be achieved by using `Arrays.sort` with your own `Comparator`

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

  String[][] array = createArray();

  Arrays.sort(array, new Comparator<String[]>() {
    @Override public int compare(String[] o1, String[] o2) {
      String day1 = o1[0];
      String day2 = o2[0];
      String time1 = o1[1];
      String time2 = o2[1];

      // Perform comparison, first of the days, then - if they're
      // identical of the times.
      return ...
    }
  });

}
```

However, as others have written in the comments: I **strongly** advise you to take a more object orientated approach to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an array here with some "virtual type structure" known to you but not to java.   Use strongly-typed class modelling.  Implement `Comparable` for sorting. Then use [collections](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/package-summary.html) - add object instances to a `List` and use it's `sort` method.

```
 class Event implements Comparable<Event> {
    String day;
    String time;

    public Event(String day, String time) { this.day = day; this.time = time; }
    public String getDay() { return this.day; }
    public String getTime() { return this.time; }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object other) {
        boolean result = false;
        if (other != null && other instanceof Event) {
            Event otherEvent = (Event)other;
            result = this.getDay().equals(otherEvent.getDay()) && 
                     this.getTime().equals(otherEvent.getTime());
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
         return this.getDay().hashCode()*7 + this.getDay().hashCode();
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Event otherEvent) {
        int result = this.getDay().compareTo(otherEvent.getDay());
        if (result == 0) result = this.getTime().compareTo(otherEvent.getTime());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then in some other class or main method:

```
List<Event> eventList = new ArrayList<Event>();
eventList.add(new Event("tuesday","20:00"));
eventList.add(new Event("tuesday","20:00"));
// etc

eventList.sort();
```